# Java Regular Expression is Not Matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple program where I am trying to match Date with a String using Regular Expression. Here is my Program

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("((?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s*\\d{1,2}\\,\\s*\\d{4})\\s*\\|\\s*UPDATED", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
String textRegion = "<span>India Today Online</span>"
            + " New Delhi, October 28, 2013 | UPDATED 11:42 IST "
            + "</div>";
Matcher m = r.matcher(textRegion);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Matched");
}
```

But When I run this program it shows "Not Matched" But when I tried same things on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it shows me the matched string. Please help me to understand where I am wrong.

I am facing interesting issue. I have two parts of my program first is showing Not Matched while second part is showing Matched. Infirst part I copied a String from a text file. I am not able to understand the issue.

```
String textRegion = "<span>India Today Online</span>"
                + " New Delhi, October 28, 2013 | UPDATED  IST"
                + "</div>";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("((?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s*\\d{1,2}\\,\\s*\\d{4})\\s*\\|\\s*UPDATED", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

         System.out.println(textRegion);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(textRegion);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Matched");
        }



        Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile("((?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s*\\d{1,2}\\,\\s*\\d{4})\\s*\\|\\s*UPDATED", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        String textRegion1 = "<span>India Today Online</span>"
                    + " New Delhi, October 28, 2013 | UPDATED  IST"
                    + "</div>";
        Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(textRegion1);
        if (m1.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Matched");
        }
```

Interesting part is if you will copy the program from here Its working fine for me as well.

Comment: Even I got *Matched* when I ran your code. Are you sure that it shows *Not Matched*?

Comment: I also got the "Matched" message when running the code. You may have less of a problem than you think. ;)

Comment: You don't need to escape comma as `\\,`

Comment: I ran the code and got Matched as well.

Comment: Guys, I am facing interesting issue. I have two parts of my program first is showing Not Matched while second part is showing Matched. Infirst part I copied a String from a text file. I am not able to understand the issue. I have provided the code of this program is well. As the part of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and found that Java treat Space and Non-breaking space ([enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) differently thats why its not giving same result for both the code parts. I added one line in my code and then it worked perfectly fine.

```
textRegion = textRegion.replaceAll("\\u00a0"," ");
```

This code replaces Non-breaking Space with a Space. As I mentioned in my program that I copied the text from somewhere else and that copied text had those Non-breaking Space instead of Space. But when you all copied code from here it worked perfectly fine as your copied code did not have Non-breaking Space.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using correct imports.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```